# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/Instant;

Tags: java, android, java-8

Currenty, I am unable to resolve the crash that is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/Instant;` Such crash happens with Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) and below. But my Oreo emulator runs `Instant.parse(...)` just fine.

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/Instant;
                  at (application class)
                  at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.time.Instant" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/(app-domain)/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/(app-domain)/lib/arm64, /data/app/(app-domain)/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/(app-domain)/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                  at (application class)
                  at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**Offending code:**

`Date parseDate = Date.from(Instant.parse(model.getDate() + "Z"));`

Where `model` is a date `String` with format `"yyyy-mm-ddTkk:mm:ss"`

My JDK version is at 1.8 now. I understand that I should indicate backport functionality, thus in my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.2-2018-04-16"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
...

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
     implementation "com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.5"
}
```

And based on what I have read here, apparently `Instant.parse(...)` isn't included in the supported APIs: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features

What could I be missing? I might as well use the *"[ailing `Date` and `Calendar` APIs in both Java and Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)"* instead, but that would be the last resort. I would like to stick to what JDK 1.8 has to offer whenever possible.

Besides, I am not comfortable using Joda Time, since it's too big for such a small app that I am developing, and that I only need a couple of functions in such a case.

Any input would be appreciated!

**Nota bene**: Contract explicitly wants me to use Java instead of Kotlin.

Comment: you shoud try a clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you open the sdk documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/Instant.html you see in the upper right corner **"added in API level 26"** which means the class is not available on older android devices.

Your manifest contains **minSdkVersion 19**. This means i promise that my app will run on api-19 and newer. The exception tells you that the promise is broken.

How to solve:

- Either: Do not use `Instant` to keep compatibility with android-api-19. You can try to use SimpleDateFormat to parse the date from string-format to date-format.
- Or: Tell your manifest that the app requieres api-26 and newer with **minSdkVersion 26**. This means that you cannot install your app on a android-api-19 device any more

Comment: Thank you @k3b. I opted for the first option, since I needed the people who use `android-api-19` :)

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered exactly the same error after updating some dependency. Resigning from it or changing the minSdkVersion to 26 wasn't an option. I fixed it by enabling the desugaring support described in [Java 8+ API desugaring support (Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+)](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring). The following version helped in my case:

```
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

```
https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-android
```

You should add this in `dependencies` of file `build.gradle (:app)`, version `1.0.9` or larger may not working

```
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

Core library desugaring can cause this type of error to happen. In my case it happened when building a release type build with proguard and when trying run a debug apk on a physical device. What fixed it for me was turning off core library desugaring.

```
compileOptions {
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled false
}
```